# Executing arbitrary code in python3 via stdin

Tags: python-3.x, stdout, stdin

**DISCLAIMER** I am asking how to shoot myself in the foot.

I have a trusted process `A` that writes to stdout commands that can be suitably interpreted and executed in some ongoing `python3` interpreter process `B.py`

Is there a standard `python3` way of accomplishing this.

I imagine something like this could work:

## B.py

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input():
    exec(line)
```

Invoke:
`A | python3 B.py`

Comment: Well, did you try that?  Did it work? If it didn't work, how did it fail?

Comment: You already have a program that can execute arbitrary Python code via stdin...  it's called python.  Just do ``A | python3``.  Your B.py idea would be limited to code blocks that are entirely complete in a single line - defining a function or a class that way would be tricky.

Comment: @larsks The behaviour of `B.py` works as intended. I am curious to know if there is a standard approach.

Comment: @jasonharper `A | python3` is what I was after. The idea with B.py is you could have required classes/functions already defined in `B.py` and process `A` would emit commands like `turtle.forward(1)` and later `turtle.forward(2)`.

Comment: ``A`` could still do something like ``import B`` to make its functions available for use.